# Search Tumblr Tags with Tagged Method Endpoint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, tumblr

I'm trying to search Tumblr using the tagged method. Is there a way to do this with the Tumblr gem? If not, how can I parse the API response and store the posts in a database? The gem I'm using is called Tumblr Wrapper: https://github.com/forthemakers/tumblr_wrapper. No where in the documentation is anything about using the tagged method. I'm trying to search Tumblr tagged media for the tag Kanye West. Here's how I'm trying to do it in my Post model.

```
    def self.pull_tumblr 
        Tumblr.tagged("kanye+west", :type => "photo").each do |post|
          unless exists?(post_id: post.id)
            create!(
              post_id: post.id,
              content: post.caption,
              username: post.blog_name,
              profile_photo: post.avatar_url,
              created_at: post.date,
              photo: post.photo.url
            )
          end
        end
      end
```

Comment: Add more information, your code to get answer to your problem quickly.